# Xslt Conditional Sort twice with N values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="content">
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="content">
        <movies>
        <xsl:for-each select="/movies/movie">

            <xsl:for-each select="movie[starts-with(name,'Ka')]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="vdate" />           
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="/movies/movie">
                <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 50">
                    <xsl:value-of select="vdate"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="number" order="'.($this->_boolAscending?'ascending':'descending').'"/>
            <movie>               
                <vdate><xsl:value-of select="vdate"/></vdate>
                <no><xsl:value-of select="no"/></no>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
                <link1><xsl:value-of select="link1"/></link1>
                <link2><xsl:value-of select="link2"/></link2>
                <link3><xsl:value-of select="link3"/></link3>
                <year><xsl:value-of select="year"/></year>
            </movie>


        </xsl:for-each>
        </movies>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <movies>
    <movie><no>2013001</no>
    <date>20131213</date>
    <vdate>13-12-2013</vdate>
    <name>Kalyana Kanavugal</name>
    <mlink1>http://www.moviebunk.com/?t7f4vm15zza5xv8</mlink1>
    <mlink2>http://www.moviebunk.com/?mvz1tjks2z571fj</mlink2>
    <mlink3>http://www.moviebunk.com/?k64p6yjfl5b24z4</mlink3>
    <link1><![CDATA[<a href="index2.php?q=K176AZ0DN8LW930D0ZYJ8T74P">320KBPS</a>]]></link1>
    <link2><![CDATA[<a href="index3.php?q=5245C918Z99SOHBRU6298G13M">256KBPS</a>]]></link2>
    <link3><![CDATA[<a href="index4.php?q=3FZ0MJ8S65749XBSI0670ARH2">128KBPS</a>]]></link3>
    <year>2011</year>
    </movie>

    <movie><no>2013002</no>
    <date>20131110</date>
    <vdate>10-11-2013</vdate>
    <name>Kandaudan</name>
    <mlink1>http://www.moviebunk.com/?d2411v82s08x1b2</mlink1>
    <mlink2>http://www.moviebunk.com/?gd0ume8bdo6lazg</mlink2>
    <mlink3>http://www.moviebunk.com/?gyry7qb81kvnind</mlink3>
    <link1><![CDATA[<a href="index2.php?q=6A29SM5TI180BJD50E97VTMQM">320KBPS</a>]]></link1>
    <link2><![CDATA[<a href="index3.php?q=1MGEFRH6H675H6599G0APR0KZ">256KBPS</a>]]></link2>
    <link3><![CDATA[<a href="index4.php?q=83GDW3645XHF296HY3XUEO96A">128KBPS</a>]]></link3>
    <year>2011</year>
    </movie>

    <movie><no>2013003</no>
    <date>20121019</date>
    <vdate>19-10-2012</vdate>
    <name>Koyambedu Perundhu Nilayam</name>
    <mlink1>http://www.moviebunk.com/?bdb6a76twx4kfnb</mlink1>
    <mlink2>http://www.moviebunk.com/?n56o5xuqc7euqq6</mlink2>
    <mlink3>http://www.moviebunk.com/?wksvaa965pp6a1e</mlink3>
    <link1><![CDATA[<a href="index2.php?q=5R9B6916IN5H5R6G4O37G3XB3">320KBPS</a>]]></link1>
    <link2><![CDATA[<a href="index3.php?q=TM7ZFY8619W371P972P92R51F">256KBPS</a>]]></link2>
    <link3><![CDATA[<a href="index4.php?q=HQ6YHH751Y7M0H8ZK60V773U3">128KBPS</a>]]></link3>
    <year>2011</year>
    </movie>
    </movies>
```

I am new to XSLT programming. Please suggest me a way to sort an XML file.
I have problems with sorting as follows: name starts with 'K' letter, then sort with descending order. Display only the first 50 values. I tried sorting without starts with 'Ka'and limiting the results - this works fine.

The html Output like this

`Movie Information
=================
Kalyana Kanavugal
2011
Download-320KBPS
Download-256KBPS
Download-128KBPS


Kandaudan
2011
Download-320KBPS
Download-256KBPS
Download-128KBPS


Koyambedu Perundhu Nilayam
2011
Download-320KBPS
Download-256KBPS
Download-128KBPS`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question to show the output you are expecting? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> name starts with 'K' letter, then sort [**by date?**] with descending
>   order. Display only the first 50 values.

If I understand you correctly, then this should be sufficient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" 
 cdata-section-elements="link1 link2 link3"/>

<xsl:template match="/movies">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="movie[starts-with(name, 'K')]">
        <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
<xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 50">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="vdate"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="no"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="link1"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="link2"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="link3"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="year"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Addition:**
For HTML output, try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/movies">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Movie Information</h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="movie[starts-with(name, 'K')]">
        <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
<xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 50">
    <h4>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
    </h4>
    <p>
        Download - <xsl:value-of select="link1" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br/>
        Download - <xsl:value-of select="link2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br/>
        Download - <xsl:value-of select="link3" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </p>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You sloved my problem.It Works perfectly in xml data output. while using in html output not getting hyperlink value.

Comment: @user2162901 I have added a variant with HTML output.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing work and time. It works perfectly. Thank you once again.